# R ls(pattern=...) programmatically within sapply

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I can't get the following to work.

I create 6 variables `A_N` and `B_N` where `N=1:3`. I want to grab values from namespace using a numeric vector and `sapply`. Outside `sapply`, `ls(pattern=paste0(...))` seems to work. But within `sapply`, it fails.

```
rm(list=ls())
A_1 <- letters[1]
A_2 <- letters[1]
A_3 <- letters[1]
B_1 <- letters[1]
B_2 <- letters[1]
B_3 <- letters[1]
ls()
# [1] "A_1" "A_2" "A_3" "B_1" "B_2" "B_3"

N <- c(1, 2)

ls(pattern=paste0("A_", 1))
# [1] "A_1"

sapply(N, function(i) ls(pattern=paste0("A_", i)))
# [[1]]
# character(0)

# [[2]]
# character(0)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has to do with the fact that sapply functions run in their own environment, you can get the parent environment as follows:

```
sapply(N, function(i) ls(pattern=paste0("A_", i),envir=parent.env(environment())))
```

Output:

```
[1] "A_1" "A_2"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks!